# Budgie Desktop keeps asking for password every time I open an app

Tags: password, ubuntu-budgie

How can I stop having Budgie ask for my password every time I want to open some apps, e.g. synaptic package manager always asks for a password when I open it.

Comment: synaptic needs root permission. There is no way to avoid this one.

Comment: Why the "an app" in the title and not specify that it is synaptic?  Password is asked when needed so you need to live with it. In Linux we take security serious ;)

Comment: Note: the apps that ask for password are the type that change system-wide settings, e.g. install programs as is the case with synaptic, apt, apt-get and all these...

Comment: @Rinzwind I did put e.g. to show that Synaptic was an example, I was serious when I asked the question. "Password is asked when needed..." pretty much sums up the answer to my question.

Comment: @Organic Marble I now see that from answers to my question that there is no way to avoid this one.

Comment: @Hannu, very clear explanation why password is needed. That , I can see why the need for password, I now am not so frustrated...

Comment: @AldoCaldore generally you also only need synaptic when you just installed. I almost never use synaptic/software center myself  30 minutes after installing Ubuntu and have a post-install script to set most in 1 go as well.  You just need to get the hang of it ;-)

Comment: oh do you want an answer? or let this just go? :D

Comment: @Rinzwind Of course I want an answer, that's why I asked the question. Is there more to to your previous answer? Please let me know how I can disable the popup. I am the only one using the PC, so passwords for this type of situation does not apply here.

Answer (score 0):

Linux/Ubuntu will always ask for `sudo` and once per 15 minutes, to enter your admin password when system settings are to be changed. That includes installing, updating software and altering settings.

If you are the only user of your system that can be annyoing but in my experience most of these are done just after installing. During the regular time using the desktop you will not see that asked that often. But you should accept the need of that password: it is one of the things that keeps your system safer.

What I did to make an install go smoother is create a text file with all the alterations I make to the system (`gsettings` for settings, `apt install` and `apt purge` to add and remove software, I also have a backup of `~./config/users-dirs.dir` I copy over the installed one).
That way you have to insert the password once for that set of changes.

And when it is all as I want it the only time I need it is when there are system updates.